# How to fix "This dictionary requires a model item of type" in Asp.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

Here is my model class
Where is my mistake ?

And error message I received;
**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[NePisirsem.Models.EntitiyFramework.iletisim]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'NePisirsem.Models.Uye'**

```
public partial class iletisim
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Ad { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public byte Konu { get; set; }
    public string Mesaj { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
    PanelEntities db = new PanelEntities();

    // GET: Admin
    public ActionResult Panel()
    {
        var model = db.iletisim.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

My View

```
 @model List<NePisirsem.Models.EntitiyFramework.iletisim>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Ad</td>
            <td>@item.Email</td>
            <td>@item.Konu</td>
            <td>@item.Mesaj</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a snippet of the stacktrace as well?

Comment: The view you've shown is not the one your code tries to use. Post real [MCVE].

Comment: Does your layout file expect a certain type of model? What happens if you put `@{ Layout = null; }` at the top your view?

Comment: Thank you guy's for your help especially you @itsme86 i fixed error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make sure that the model passed in view is compatible(same as passed model) with the model being used inside View,

Compare the namespace where both classes are defined they should be same.Classes should be same

**Example:**

if you are using

> NePisirsem.Models.EntitiyFramework.iletisim

inside view as model then your class iletisim should be like this inside Model folder

```
namespace EntityFramework
{

 public partial class iletisim
 {
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Ad { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public byte Konu { get; set; }
public string Mesaj { get; set; }
 }

}
```

You can also check if both classes are same by using type check

```
    Type viewModel = typeof(List<NePisirsem.Models.EntitiyFramework.iletisim>());
    Type controllerModel = typeof(iletisim);

  if(!controllerModel.Equals(viewModel))
   //MOdel not matches
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already fixed error. I use layout and my layout contains "NePisirsem.Models.Uye" not this @model List<NePisirsem.Models.EntitiyFramework.iletisim>

Comment: exactly ,have a nice day

Comment: Thank you, you too

Comment: please hit vote up if you think it was correct